# finding miniums distance between two subsets of vertices

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph

Given an undirected graph G=(V,E) , V1,V2 are subsets of V.
`d(V1,V2)=min d(v1,v2)` ,  [image]
so I need to figure out how to find d(V1,V2) in `O(|V|+|E|)`

if    [image]  then `d(V1,V2)=0`

otherwise, I randomly pick v1' from V1 and run BFS(V1,v1'),  save the furthest vertex from v1'
at v1''
I will do the same for some random vertex v2' from V2.
return d(V1,V2)=min{ d(v1',v2'), d(v1',v2''),d(v1''v2'),d(v1'',v2'')}

will that work? since runtime of BFS is O(|V|+|E|) the suggested algorithm will run in O(|V|+|E|)

Comment: No it won't. Consider the case where both your starting nodes and your end nodes are just not that pair of nodes with distance 1 in your graph.

Comment: Are the edges weighted?

Comment: @AlexandruBarbarosie no

Comment: In this case either BFS on all pairs, complexity: `O(|V1|*|V2|*(|V| + |E|))` and pick min after. Or you can start BFS from each vertex of `V1` and on every level check if any of the reached vertices is in `V2`, as soon as you find a vertex you stop the BFS and compare the result with min.

Comment: If you are able to modify the data structure adding some flag which correspond to either `V1` or `V2` you will reduce the "check" described above to O(1) and since it is O(1) you can also add some test cases like: if you start from V1 and BFS reaches a vertex from V1 do not branch further from that vertex. This can reduce drastically the average complexity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IMO what you can do is as follows:

1. Scan the set V1 and note all edges that begin at nodes in V1 and end at nodes not in V1.
2. Now combine all the nodes in V1 into one node. The edges noted in step 1 shall be the edges going out from this node.
3. Do the same for V2.
4. Now it reduces to the shortest route problem between node V1 and V2. This can be solved by conducting a simple BFS on node V1 or V2 in O(E) where E is the number of edges in the graph.

Comment: I think this is good enough, if you are careful enough it will run `O(M)`, where `M` is the number of edges in the graph. However, you need no Dijkstra's algorithm. Plain BFS will do as the graph is not weighted (furthermore Dijkstra increases the complexity).

Comment: Yet one more edit is needed - DFS is not suitable for finding shortest route between two vertices in random graph.